# Java Dialog close returns same value as cancel?

Tags: java, javafx, dialog

I'm trying to write a dialog function that returns an int value (1, -1, or 0) according to the user's choice ('confirm', 'no', or close the dialog).

But whenever I close the dialog, it returns the same value as selecting the 'no' button.

is there a way to solve this issue?

Thank you in advance :)

> /**   * Shows a confirm box and returns an integer value of the user
>   selection      * @param title      * @param text   * @return       * @return 1
>   if confirmed, -1 if not confirmed, 0 if canceled   */

```
public static int strictConfirmBox(String title, String text, String yesString, String noString) {
    ButtonType okBttn = new ButtonType(yesString, ButtonData.YES);
    ButtonType noBttn = new ButtonType(noString, ButtonData.NO);

    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION, text, noBttn, okBttn);
    alert.setTitle(title);
    alert.setHeaderText(null);
    alert.setGraphic(null);
    Label msg = new Label(text);
    msg.setWrapText(true);
    alert.getDialogPane().setContent(msg);

    alert.showAndWait();



    if(alert.getResult()==ButtonType.CLOSE){
        //closed dialog
        return 0;
    }else if(alert.getResult()==ButtonType.YES){
        //selected yes
        return 1;
    }
    // else if(alert.getResult()==ButtonType.NO){
    //selected no
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: https://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/  Look for `Confirmation Dialog with Custom Actions`.

Comment: You are missing the `Optional<ButtonType> result`.

Answer (score 2):

Code in `javafx.scene.control.Dialog.close()` finds the first button which returns true to isCancelButton(). This behaviour is documented at length under "*Dialog Closing Rules*" in the [official Javadoc for javafx.scene.control.Dialog.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html)

```
for (ButtonType button : getDialogPane().getButtonTypes()) {
    ButtonData buttonData = button.getButtonData();
    if (buttonData == null) continue;

    if (buttonData == ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE) {
        cancelButton = button;
        break;
    }
    if (buttonData.isCancelButton()) {
        cancelButton = button;
    }
}
```

Therefore the best I can suggest is to use the "OTHER" type instead of the ButtonData.NO type. This will prevent the dialog being closed so user is forced to choose YES or NO

```
ButtonType okBttn = new ButtonType("yes", ButtonData.YES);
ButtonType noBttn = new ButtonType("no", ButtonData.OTHER);
```

Alternatively you could add an explicit close option, which will get chosen if dialog is manually closed.

```
ButtonType okBttn = new ButtonType("yes", ButtonData.YES);
ButtonType noBttn = new ButtonType("no", ButtonData.OTHER);
ButtonType closeButton = new ButtonType("Close", ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code comes from https://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/. You should use `Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();`. It returns the result after an action is taken. Use that result and an `if-statement` to return the value needed.

```
Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
alert.setTitle("Confirmation Dialog with Custom Actions");
alert.setHeaderText("Look, a Confirmation Dialog with Custom Actions");
alert.setContentText("Choose your option.");

ButtonType buttonTypeOne = new ButtonType("One");
ButtonType buttonTypeTwo = new ButtonType("Two");
ButtonType buttonTypeThree = new ButtonType("Three");
ButtonType buttonTypeCancel = new ButtonType("Cancel", ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);

alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(buttonTypeOne, buttonTypeTwo, buttonTypeThree, buttonTypeCancel);

Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
if (result.get() == buttonTypeOne){
    // ... user chose "One"
} else if (result.get() == buttonTypeTwo) {
    // ... user chose "Two"
} else if (result.get() == buttonTypeThree) {
    // ... user chose "Three"
} else {
    // ... user chose CANCEL or closed the dialog
}
```